# Are $\Pi_2$ consequences of universal theories witnessed by finitely many terms?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Here is  a question in model theory I need help. Suppose $T$ be a set of universal sentences and $T\models\forall x\exists y\:P(x,y)$. Prove that there exists terms $t_1(x),\cdots,t_n(x)$ such that
$$
T\models\forall x \bigvee^n_{k=1}P(x,t_k)
$$
Intuitively, it is obvious true but I need a rigorous proof which should involve the compactness theorem.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Maybe you can begin by explaining why you think this is obviously true - that may lead to a proof. Note that your explanation needs to rely on the fact that $T$ is a set of universal sentences, since this is obviously *false* for general first-order theories $T$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman The statement itself is false as written - what if the language of $T$ has no terms at all?

Comment: @AlexKruckman What about taking $T$ to be empty, and $P(x,y)$ to be "If there are two distinct elements then $x\not=y$, and otherwise $x=y$"? Then $T\models\forall x\exists y P(x,y)$, but there's only one term in $x$ (namely, $x$ itself) and $T\not\models \forall x P(x,x)$. We need an additional condition on $P$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman That doesn't solve the problem as far as I can tell. $T$ still satisfies $\forall x\exists yP(x,y)$ since if the structure is empty that sentence is vacuously true.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think $P$ is supposed to be quantifier-free (or maybe even atomic, but I think both should work). I agree, this should be specified.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oops, I agree your counterexample works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired result turns out to be a form of Herbrand's Theorem.  The statement given in the question is virtually identical to one appearing in the paper "On Herbrand's Theorem" by Samuel R. Buss, as shown here:

[image: Weak Herbrand's Theorem]

That paper appears In "Logic and Computational Complexity, Lecture Notes in Computer Science #960", 1995, Springer-Verlag, pp. 195-209 and is available online. Buss's proof however is proof-theoretic, and so is the proof sketch on the Wikipedia page for the theorem.

This question as posed here however is for a proof in model theory.  There is a model-theoretic proof in Joseph Shoenfield's classic text "Mathematical Logic" (1967), and you can find Shoenfield's exposition revisited in detail in a bachelor's thesis by E. J. Gerritse, available online at https://www.cs.ru.nl/bachelors-theses/2015/Emma_Gerritse___4248120___Herbrands_theorem.pdf.

It seems inappropriate to recap the rather lengthy model-theoretic proof in an answer here, so please refer to one of these high-quality sources.

In spite of the request for a proof that uses compactness and the alleged application of compactness in another answer, I do not believe there is any appeal to compactness in these model-theoretic proofs.  It would be interesting to see if compactness can play a role.

Comment: The proof in the bachelor's thesis you linked is entirely proof-theoretic, not model-theoretic.

Comment: @EricWofsey That does appear to be true. Shoenfield introduces some of the concepts ("special constants" at least) in the context of the completeness theorem (model theory), but that looks incidental at this point. At least I do not see model theory in the actual proof.

Comment: @EricWofsey Shoenfield does have a definition of compactness and a compactness theorem, so he presumably could use them to get a short and sweet proof of this form of Herbrand's theorem as you do, but he does not. So far I also find no proof that looks like yours in other literature, which fuels my skepticism, for better or worse. Regardless of all of this, thanks for your responsiveness. I will ask more questions and am prepared to modify my answer when more rested.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that $P$ is supposed to be quantifier-free; otherwise, as discussed in the comments, the result is false.

First, note that since $T$ consists of universal sentences, if $M$ is any model of $T$, then any substructure of $M$ is also a model of $T$.  In particular, given $a\in M$, the substructure $N$ generated by $a$ consists of elements represented by terms in $a$, and $N\models\exists y P(a,y)$.  Thus, there is a term $t(a)$ such that $N\models P(a,t(a))$, and hence $M\models P(a,t(a))$ as well since $P$ is quantifier-free.

So, for any $a$ in any model of $T$, there is some term $t(a)$ such that $P(a,t(a))$ is true.  In other words, adding a constant symbol $c$ to the language, the infinite disjunction $\bigvee_i P(c,t_i(c))$ is true in every model of $T$, where $t_i$ ranges over all possible terms.  By compactness, there must be finitely many $t_1,\dots,t_n$ such that $T\models\bigvee_{k=1}^n P(c,t_k(c))$, and so $T\models \forall x \bigvee_{k=1}^n P(x,t_k(x))$

Comment: Your argument also works if $P$ is an existential formula, since it only requires the truth of $P$ to go up from $N$ to $M$.

Comment: Good point.  An even stronger generalization would be to let $x$ and $y$ be tuples of variables instead of single variables (so, any existential quantifiers in $P$ could be pulled out to be part of $\exists y$).

Comment: What if T contains a single sentence, ∀. x = 1, where 1 is a constant? Taking P(x, y)  to be x = y, it is then true that  ⊨ ∀∃(,). I see that the one sentence in T is true, but no more in the language of T. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: @CrisP: I don't understand what you are trying to say about that example.  $1$ is a term, so you could take $n=1$ and $t_1$ to be $1$.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey So the intention is that there only needs to exist some positive n?

Comment: @CrisP: Yes, $n$ is not fixed.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey This is a new field to me, but I'm concerned that in many cases you do not get. a substructure by restricting the function domains. It appears the proof relies on being able to generate a substructure from an element of the original domain M.

Comment: @CrisP: The substructure generated by $a$ is the smallest substructure containing $a$.  So it's not just $\{a\}$, but the closure of $\{a\}$ under all the functions.

Comment: @EricWofsey Excellent, but aren't you in need of a substructure that is finite? Peano-like formulas such as: N(0); N(x) → N(S(x)); S(x) ≠ 0; S(x) = S(y) → x = y are universal but cannot be jointly satisfied by a finite structure.

Comment: @CrisP: No, there is no reason the substructure needs to be finite.

Comment: @EricWofsey Can you give a reference to the result that when T consists of universal sentences, any substructure of a model of it is also a model? Tnx.

Comment: @CrisP: I don't know one but the proof is trivial.  If $\varphi(x)$ is a quantifier-free formula which is true for all $x\in M$, then it is also true for all $x\in N$ if $N\subseteq M$, since every $x\in N$ is also in $M$.

Comment: @EricWofsey What do you mean by "terms in a", when "a" is in the model rather than the language? And how can there be a term t(a) when "a" is not in the language?

Comment: @EricWofsey How can you speak of an infinite disjunction being true in every model given that a formal language typically does not have infinite formulas?

Comment: @CrisP: By "term in $a$" I mean an element of $M$ you get by evaluating some term $t(x)$ by substituting $a$ for $x$.  For the infinite disjunction, I mean nothing more than the fact that for any model, there is some $i$ such that $P(c,t_i(c))$ is true in that model.